Download dotfiles when SSH-ing with a bash login shell
I'm working with a lot of remote Ubuntu hosts that are changing a lot. To have a streamlined workflow on all hosts I'm downloading my personal dotfiles with bash aliases, small exes and configurations onto these servers upon login and source the new bash files. For this I have aliased my ssh command to this:
ssh() {
    command ssh -t -o RemoteCommand="git -C '/tmp/myuser/dotfiles' pull --rebase \
         || git clone https://github.com/MyUser/dotfiles.git '/tmp/myuser/dotfiles'; \
            bash --rcfile '/tmp/myuser/dotfiles/.bashrc' -i" "$@"
}

This worked reliably so far, however the issue here is that this alias sometimes gets in the way. One case is for example if I want to execute a command on the remote host from my local machine without logging into the host:
ssh foreign.host 'curl http://localhost:8888/say/hello'

In that case ssh will complain with Cannot execute command-line and remote command. (since the remote command is already given).
Is there a way to configure OpenSSh so that only when executing a bash login shell on a host my dotfiles are fetched and sourced?

I'd suggest renaming your function, so you have a clear distinction when running ssh alone.

Or what about just command ssh foreign.host 'curl http://localhost:8888/say/hello'? That would make Bash skip function lookup entirely

I don't know if you can configure openSSH for this, but you do have two simpler options:

Change the name of the function. Have one that does what you currently have, and then just alias or write a function that does a simple ssh:
## ssh for running remote commands
alias sshc='command ssh -t'


Modify your existing function to do different things depending on whether you give it just a host name or a host name and something else which is assumed to be the command you want to run:
ssh() {
  if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
    command ssh -t "$@"
  else
    command ssh -t -o RemoteCommand="git -C '/tmp/myuser/dotfiles' pull --rebase \
     || git clone https://github.com/MyUser/dotfiles.git '/tmp/myuser/dotfiles'; \
        bash --rcfile '/tmp/myuser/dotfiles/.bashrc' -i" "$@"
  fi
}




I like the second approach. However, I still would like to find a way to do it via ssh config.

I like the first approach more instead, as the second method would "prevent" connecting to a host without injecting rc files (if ever needed in OP's case of course) in case of e.g. ssh user@host (quoting "prevent" as of course one could just prepend command - which by the way could be the solution to OP's problem to begin with...).

@glades I really doubt you can. It doesn't seem like the kind of thing one would use ssh options for. Not sure though, so maybe someone will come up with a clever solution.
